# Kotlin: Generic types in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, generics

To get the class definition to be used for example for json deserialization the following can be used in Kotlin:

```
Map::class.java
```

A example usage is the following:

```
val map =  mapper.readValue(json, Map::class.java)
```

But now how to have the generic type definition?

Something like this does not compile:

```
val map =  mapper.readValue(decodedString, Map<String, String>::class.java)
```

So my question is: What is the generic equivalent to `*::class.java`

Comment: Do you use a library (like Jackson, etc.)?

Comment: Serialisation is just an example.  I want to know the Kotlin verison of what in c# would look like `typeof(Dictrionary<string,string>)` or in scala look like `classOf[Map[String, String]]`. I would like to know what is the correct shape of `Map<String, String>::class.java`

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: `Map<String, String>::class.java` and `Map<String::class.java, String::class.java>::class.java`

Comment: Maybe it is not even possible, see: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-9193

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Class<T>` (in Java) or `KClass<T>` (in Kotlin) can only represent *classes*, not all types. If the API you're using only uses `Class<T>` or `KClass<T>`, it simply doesn't support generic types (at least in those functions).

Instead, [KType](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/-k-type/) (or `Type` in Java) is the proper type to use to represent the complete type information including generics. You could use it this way:

```kotlin
val myMapType: KType = typeOf<Map<String,String>>()
```

Unfortunately, `KType` doesn't have a type parameter (it's not `KType<T>`), and that makes it impossible to use for compile-time type checking: you can't have the equivalent of `fun deserialize(Input, KClass<T>): T` using `KType` instead of `KClass`, because you can't define the `T` for the return type by using only a `KType` argument.

There are several tricks to work around this:

- In both Java and Kotlin, one of the ways is to get this information through inheritance by providing a generic superclass and inheriting from it.

  In general, serialization APIs (especially the deserializing part) provide workarounds using this, such as Jackson's [TypeReference](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/type/TypeReference.html) or Gson's [TypeToken](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.6.2/com/google/gson/reflect/TypeToken.html). It's basically their version of `Type` but with a type parameter to have some compile-time type safety.
- In Kotlin, there is sometimes another way depending on the situation: making use of [reified type parameters](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/inline-functions.html#reified-type-parameters). Using inline functions, the compiler can know more information at compile time about the type parameters by replacing them with the actual inferred type at the call site when inlining the function's body. This allows things like `T::class` in the inline function's body. This is how you can get functions like [typeOf](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/type-of.html) to get a `KType`.

  Some Kotlin-specific APIs of deserialization libraries use inline functions to remove the hassle from the user, and get type information directly. This is what [jackson-module-kotlin](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-kotlin) does by providing an inline `readValue` extension without a `Class` argument, which reifies the type parameter to get the target type information